# this is an api authorization webapp built on node js and im facing this issue and i cannot solve it i have already installed all thenpmpackages

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

`failed to make request Cannot find module 'js' Require stack:`your text`

- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\programming\full stack web development\backend\5.3 Axios\node_modules\express\lib\view.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\programming\full stack web development\backend\5.3 Axios\node_modules\express\lib\application.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\programming\full stack web development\backend\5.3 Axios\node_modules\express\lib\express.js

i tried all the website solution uninstalling the npm packages and reinstalling them but it is not helping and i checked with the reference code i dont find any other mistake as of now the code is below `

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("``https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/random``");
    const result = response.data;
    res.render("index.ejs", { data: result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to make request:", error.message);
    res.render("index.ejs", {
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const type = (req.body.type)
    const participants = (req.body.participants)

    const response = await axios.get(`https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/filter?type=${type}&participants=${participants}`)
    const result = response.data;

    res.render("index.js", { data: result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)] });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("failed to make request", error.message);
    res.render("index.ejs",
      {
        error: "no activities match your criteria",
      })
  }

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(Server running on port: ${ port });
});
```

Comment: Make sure to : npm install ejs

Comment: It seems like you're using EJS as your template engine (since you're using .ejs extensions in your code). Make sure you have EJS installed as a dependency (npm install ejs) and set up your view engine in your Express app.

Comment: tried it and it is giving me the same error is my code right ??

Answer (score 0):

You're responding with a javascript file not the `.ejs` in this code block

```js
res.render("index.js", { data: result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)] });
```

You need to specify the correct `.ejs` file